# Load/Switch content in div w/o loading all content at once

Tags: html, css, jquery

I have a situation where I need to have a user select a region from a dropdown box.

Depending on the region selected a search form will load with information relevant to the selected region.

I tried this:
stackoverflow.com/questions/3760920/jquery-dropdown-loading-content
Loading all the forms at once really slowed it down, and there seemed to be issues with the javascript used in the search forms when all were present at once.

I think the ideal solution would be to load/unload the search into a div. I've tried several tutorials with limited success.

My most recent attempt was this tutorial:
http://www.milaju.com/post/simple-ajax-content-changer-with-ezjax

The search itself works fine as seen here by itself:
http://test.medialayer.net/test/modules/one.html

But loaded inside a div the search fields don't populate.
http://test.medialayer.net/test/

Thanks for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `window.onload=checkDataLoad;`. You use AJAX, window.onload won't work with that, simply use `checkDataLoad()`, and see [window.onload equivalent for Ajax applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694338/window-onload-equivalent-for-ajax-applications)